# Having problems with auto renewable subscription in app purchase in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, subscription, auto-renewing

I am having an app in which I am implementing Auto Renewable Subscription In App Purchase.

I am following this link [link](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit)

With that, I am getting the alert successfully to purchase but when I press it again, it asks me every time to purchase.

There are two methods mentioned in it about checking an expiration date and if the product is expired.

But I am unable to found the proper solution from that.

Can anyone please help me???

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the issue? If you are testing using sandbox account then Actual duration
Test duration
1 week =3 minutes
1 month=5 minutes
2 months=10 minutes
3 months=15 minutes
6 months=30 minutes
1 year=1 hour

Comment: Ohhhh!!! I didn't know that... Thanks.... Ok but can you please let me know from which code can we check if user has cancelled the subscription? Is this restorable???

Comment: I have set it for 1 year but it is showing me every time I run the app. User can cancel the subscription outside the app. So how to check from code that user has cancelled the subscription?

Comment: if you are doing auto renewable subscription then the only way to know if the subscription has been cancelled is by checking the transaction receipt!

Comment: Can you please show me with the line of code and where to put it???

Comment: If I have set it for one year, then will it charge only once throughout the year?

Comment: yes! and after one year itunes will automatically deduct amount for another year. Maybe it notifies the user before deducting again after a year.

Comment: Do you know how to cancel a subscription in a sandbox environment? and this subscription is not restorable, right? If user deletes the app and reinstalls it, he just have to upgrade but no money will be deducted again. Right?

Comment: unfortunately its not possible to cancel a subscription from sandbox account! that is why  they decrease the subscription period to minutes .

Comment: @JennyJose: Have you done this in app? Can you please provide me a code for this?

Comment: Actually, in my app we are doing server side verification! The same code in php.. I send the receipt ID through web service and they check whether the subscription has expired or not

Comment: @JennyJose:Ok. No Probs... But one thing is that do we need to implement restore purchase? What if user deletes the app and reinstalls?

Comment: yes! restore purchase is needed! sometimes Apple rejects the app just because you have not provided "Restore Purchases". So make sure you do that..

Comment: But there is no code for that in the link above...

Comment: Even if I successfully purchases it, it goes to both methods, "Successful transaction" and "Restore" in switch case.

Answer (score 3):

Check this link

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html

Apple suggests that the receipt validation should be done at the server side.

The status code received if the subscription has expired is  21006.

---

For RESTORING PURCHASES

```
- (IBAction)retoreinApp:(id)sender
{
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];

    self.restoringInAppStatusLabel.hidden = NO;

}
```

It will call the method after getting restore details :

```
- (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue {

    UIAlertView *alert ;
    if(queue.transactions.count >0)
    {
        for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions)
        {
            NSString *temp = transaction.payment.productIdentifier;

          NSLog(@"Product Identifier string is %@",temp);

        }

        alert = [[UIAlertView alloc ] initWithTitle:@"Restore Transactions" message:@"All your previous transactions are restored successfully." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    }
    else
    {
        alert = [[UIAlertView alloc ] initWithTitle:@"Restore Transactions" message:@"No transactions in your account to be restored." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    }
    [alert show];

}
```

Comment: Please note that validation of the receipt on the device is *not* the recommended procedure. Validation is recommended via the encryption style on >= iOS7 or via a server.

Comment: Yes! I had mentioned it in the comments that in my project we are doing server side authentication!

Comment: In your code, you are contacting *Apple's* validation server. This is not the recommended procedure.

Comment: Yes Chris! This is not the recommended procedure and I have already told Manthan that I am doing server side validation.